# View discounts for a group type

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, group

I use the "Group" and "Commerce discount" modules to make bundled sales. This is used to display discounts to certain type of group.

I have a group type (company) and group type (flash sale).

I want a 10% discount for the group (company) type on the whole catalog and a 30% discount for the group type (flash sale).

Is it possible to do this ?

Discounts must be applied to the product catalog, as in the screenshot :

Thank you

[image]

-10% and -30% are examples, I know how to create discounts. But how to apply the discounts to the group type (company) ?

I want only the members who belong to company sees the discounts.

Here is the export of a discount :

```
{
  "name" : "discount_professionnel_remise_produits_10",
  "label" : "PROFESSIONNEL Remise produits 10",
  "type" : "product_discount",
  "status" : "1",
  "component_title" : "Remise sur les produits -10%",
  "sort_order" : "10",
  "discount_usage_per_person" : [],
  "discount_usage_limit" : [],
  "commerce_discount_date" : [],
  "commerce_discount_offer" : {
    "type" : "percentage",
    "commerce_percentage" : { "und" : [ { "value" : "10.00" } ] },
    "rdf_mapping" : []
  },
  "inline_conditions" : { "und" : [
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "15" } ], "condition_logic_operator" : null },
        "condition_negate" : 0
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "16" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "17" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "18" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "19" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "20" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "21" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "22" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "23" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "24" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "25" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "26" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "27" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "28" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "29" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "30" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "31" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "32" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "74" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "76" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "63" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "64" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "65" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_product_contains_products",
        "condition_settings" : { "sku" : [ { "product_id" : "66" } ] },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "0"
      },
      {
        "condition_name" : "commerce_discount_extra_line_item_user_has_role",
        "condition_settings" : { "roles" : {
            "utilisateur M2" : "utilisateur M2",
            "utilisateur E1" : "utilisateur E1",
            "utilisateur E2" : "utilisateur E2",
            "administrateur A2" : "administrateur A2"
          }
        },
        "condition_negate" : 0,
        "condition_logic_operator" : "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "commerce_compatibility_strategy" : { "und" : [ { "value" : "any" } ] },
  "commerce_compatibility_selection" : [],
  "rdf_mapping" : []
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I still wonder about "where is the -10% and -30%?" ... Can you maybe explain how the 3 savons should look like if the 10% should be applied? And how if the 30% should be applied? Is that "on top of the discounts I already see in the image? Something else? Also, what is the entity that these group types relate to? I don't think they are "nodes", but instead I think they are products or something? I am nearly sure they are not "users" (who are buying some "Savon"). You did not explain that part of your question (and I'm confused about that, still, sorry).

Comment: Hey Mathieu, something is (still) incomplete (or wrong) in your question ... About "**members who belong to company sees the discounts.**": "company" is a group **type** (not a group, I think). So members cannot belong to such group type, they can only belong to some "group" (of a specific group type). Maybe you mean  "**members who belong to some group for which the group type is company sees the discounts**"? Also, how did you configure "flash sale"? I cannot believe that relates to "members". Maybe you mean something like a product (or line item?) that is part of a group (type)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The question is simple but I do not know how to explain. I want to apply different discounts for each type of group. For example, if I created a 10% discount on my soaps, how do I show it on the catalog only to the group type (company)? There are no conditions in discounts referring to groups (discount rules).

Comment: I think I have found a way to incorporate such conditions. But I first need to understand your Groups and Group Types. Can you add a few samples of (eg) 2 Groups for (eg) 2 Group Types? And clarify if Company is a Group or a Group Type? PS cleanup your first 2 comments?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens (company 1) and (company 2) are group types. (company 1) contains groups (group 1), (group 2), ... how to apply discounts to group type (company 1) and other discounts to group type (company 2).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Commerce Discount Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra) or use [Commerce Discount Product Category](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_product_category) modules 
This modules gives extra conditions in commmerce discount configuration

Comment: Thank you, but the two modules you propose do not propose a link with the "Group" module.